# Strange behaviour of Unanswered tab

Tags: discussion, feature-request, unanswered-questions

Clicking on the [Unanswered button](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered), you get 3 tabs :

- [my tags](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags)
- [newest](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest)
- [votes](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes)
- [no answers](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)

My tags - this tab lists answered questions, but the answer was not accepted. The questions seams to be sorted in some strange way (by number of votes). Why are they not sorted by date? Why are questions with answers listed?

Newest - this lists all possible tags listed by date. Not very useful in my opinion. Clicking on a tag that I am interested (one of favourites), switch to Questions - newest.

Votes - again not useful. Lists all tags

No answers - lists all possible tags sorted by number of votes.

What would be useful is to list favourite tags sorted by date.
Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What would be useful is to list favourite tags sorted by date. Any thoughts on this?

- Create a Tag Sets at https://stackexchange.com/tagsets/popular
- Import your current tags there
- click "newest" tab under my tag sets

[image]

Comment: Yes, that answered the question. Thanks, but it is still strange that I have to go to StackExchange, and that I could not do it directly in SO

Comment: @Vjo, If you consider Stack Overflow as a subset of Stack Exchange, that would make sense :-)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Try clicking multiple times to combine tags, too.

Comment: It redirects to unanswered sorted by number of votes, with specific tags

Comment: @vjo keep clicking there to combine tags, click slightly above that to un-combine

Comment: I bet you bought this font just for the purpose of illustrating support questions. `TechSupporter ExtraBold` :)

Answer (score 0):

> Why are questions with answers listed?

Take a look to the right, below the number of questions listed:
**questions with no upvoted answers**

No upvote usually means the answer is probably not good enough to be real answer, so the question is still considered "unanswered".

Comment: Those questions are still sorted by number of votes